# Navigating dropdown menus using selenium Select

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
#Initialization for beautifulsoup to access site for per game stats
url = "https://stats.nba.com/players/traditional/?sort=PTS&dir=-1&Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Regular%20Season"
d = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
d.get(url)

#Initializes data frame to store player data
data_df= pd.DataFrame(columns={'Player','Team','3PA','3P%','3PaTotal','Season'})

for yearCount in range(0,20):
    season = [18,19]
    seasonStr = str(season[0])+"/"+str(season[1])
    for pageCounter in range(0,11):
        #Scrapes all of the data putting it into headers
        soup = BeautifulSoup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('table')
        headers, [_, *data] = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('th')], [[i.text for i in b.find_all('td')] for b in soup.find_all('tr')]
        final_data = [i for i in data if len(i) > 1]

        #Creates a dictionary of headers
        data_attrs = [dict(zip(headers, i)) for i in final_data]

        #Collects stats that are used for graph
        players = [i['PLAYER'] for i in data_attrs]
        teams = [i['TEAM'] for i in data_attrs]
        threePointAttempts = [i['3PA'] for i in data_attrs]
        threePointPercentage = [i['3P%'] for i in data_attrs]

        #Adds the data collected to the dataframe
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Player': players,
                                'Team': teams,
                                '3PA': threePointAttempts,
                                '3P%': threePointPercentage,
                                '3PaTotal' : 0,
                                'Season' : seasonStr})
        data_df = data_df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
        data_df = data_df[['Player','Team','3PA','3P%','3PaTotal','Season']]

        #Goes to next page
        nxt = d.find_element_by_class_name("stats-table-pagination__next")
        nxt.click()

    dropDown = Select(d.find_element_by_name("Season"))
    dropDown.select_by_index(yearCount)
```

> My error code:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/brenn/PycharmProjects/NBAstats/venv/Lib/site-packages/Player
>   3-Point.py", line 44, in 
>       headers, [_, *data] = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('th')], [[i.text for i in b.find_all('td')] for b in soup.find_all('tr')]
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

I am having an issue when attempting to collect data for past seasons on the NBA site. My code collects all of the player data for the current season (iterating through each page with no issues). But when I try to collect the data from the past year by navigating through the dropdown it does not work. If I use the URL of the past season, without using the dropdown menu navigation it collects the data with no issue. Also in the selenium chrome tab, the page switches to the past year but runs into the issue when attempting to read the data.

Comment: Show expected result sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love working with sports data!

I'd like to suggest a slightly different method. The data is rendered through a request url that will return a json response. You can use the query parameters for that to iterate through the seasons (starting in 1996). Then you can dump the whole thing into a dataframe and filter/manipulate that dataframe anyway you want.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


request_url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'}

results = pd.DataFrame()
for yearCount in range(1996,2019):
    season = int(str(yearCount)[-2:])
    seasonStr = '%02d/%02d' %(int(str(season)[-2:]), int(str(season+1)[-2:]))
    season_query = '%s-%s' %(yearCount, str(yearCount+1)[-2:])

    params = {
    'College': '',
    'Conference':'', 
    'Country': '',
    'DateFrom': '',
    'DateTo': '',
    'Division': '',
    'DraftPick': '',
    'DraftYear': '',
    'GameScope': '',
    'GameSegment': '',
    'Height': '',
    'LastNGames': '0',
    'LeagueID': '00',
    'Location': '',
    'MeasureType': 'Base',
    'Month': '0',
    'OpponentTeamID': '0',
    'Outcome': '',
    'PORound': '0',
    'PaceAdjust': 'N',
    'PerMode': 'PerGame',
    'Period': '0',
    'PlayerExperience':'', 
    'PlayerPosition': '',
    'PlusMinus': 'N',
    'Rank': 'N',
    'Season': season_query,
    'SeasonSegment': '',
    'SeasonType': 'Regular Season',
    'ShotClockRange': '',
    'StarterBench': '',
    'TeamID': '0',
    'TwoWay': '0',
    'VsConference': '', 
    'VsDivision': '',
    'Weight': ''}


    jsonObj = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers, params=params).json()

    cols = jsonObj['resultSets'][0]['headers']
    rows = jsonObj['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)
    for row in rows:
        row_df = pd.DataFrame([row], columns = cols)
        temp_df = temp_df.append(row_df)

    temp_df['Season'] = seasonStr

    print ('Aquired %s stats' %(seasonStr))
    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(results)
      PLAYER_ID            PLAYER_NAME  ...              CFPARAMS Season
0          1489                   None  ...                 1489,  96/97
1           902                   None  ...                  902,  96/97
2          2179                   None  ...                 2179,  96/97
3          1049                   None  ...                 1049,  96/97
4           775                   None  ...                  775,  96/97
5            93                   None  ...                   93,  96/97
6           920             A.C. Green  ...        920,1610612742  96/97
7           243            Aaron McKie  ...        243,1610612765  96/97
8          1425         Aaron Williams  ...       1425,1610612763  96/97
9           768              Acie Earl  ...        768,1610612749  96/97
10          228             Adam Keefe  ...        228,1610612762  96/97
11          154        Adrian Caldwell  ...        154,1610612755  96/97
12          673         Alan Henderson  ...        673,1610612737  96/97
13         1059  Aleksandar Djordjevic  ...       1059,1610612757  96/97
14          275          Allan Houston  ...        275,1610612752  96/97
15          947          Allen Iverson  ...        947,1610612755  96/97
16          297        Alonzo Mourning  ...        297,1610612748  96/97
17          175           Alton Lister  ...        175,1610612738  96/97
18         1043         Amal McCaskill  ...       1043,1610612753  96/97
19          692        Andrew DeClercq  ...        692,1610612744  96/97
20          457            Andrew Lang  ...        457,1610612749  96/97
21          358      Anfernee Hardaway  ...        358,1610612753  96/97
22          924       Anthony Goldwire  ...        924,1610612743  96/97
23          193          Anthony Mason  ...        193,1610612766  96/97
24          292         Anthony Miller  ...        292,1610612737  96/97
25          324         Anthony Peeler  ...        324,1610612763  96/97
26          156           Antoine Carr  ...        156,1610612762  96/97
27          952         Antoine Walker  ...        952,1610612738  96/97
28          213          Antonio Davis  ...        213,1610612754  96/97
29          176         Antonio Harvey  ...        176,1610612760  96/97
        ...                    ...  ...                   ...    ...
10599    204020          Tyler Johnson  ...     204020,1610612756  18/19
10600   1628399            Tyler Lydon  ...    1628399,1610612743  18/19
10601   1627755             Tyler Ulis  ...    1627755,1610612741  18/19
10602    203092           Tyler Zeller  ...     203092,1610612737  18/19
10603    201936           Tyreke Evans  ...     201936,1610612754  18/19
10604   1627820         Tyrone Wallace  ...    1627820,1610612746  18/19
10605      2199         Tyson Chandler  ...       2199,1610612747  18/19
10606   1626145             Tyus Jones  ...    1626145,1610612750  18/19
10607      2617          Udonis Haslem  ...       2617,1610612748  18/19
10608    203506         Victor Oladipo  ...     203506,1610612754  18/19
10609      1713           Vince Carter  ...       1713,1610612737  18/19
10610   1629053        Vincent Edwards  ...    1629053,1610612745  18/19
10611   1627735        Wade Baldwin IV  ...    1627735,1610612757  18/19
10612    201961        Wayne Ellington  ...     201961,1610612765  18/19
10613   1627782           Wayne Selden  ...    1627782,1610612741  18/19
10614   1628976     Wendell Carter Jr.  ...    1628976,1610612741  18/19
10615   1628411             Wes Iwundu  ...    1628411,1610612753  18/19
10616    202325         Wesley Johnson  ...     202325,1610612764  18/19
10617    202083        Wesley Matthews  ...     202083,1610612754  18/19
10618    203115            Will Barton  ...     203115,1610612743  18/19
10619   1626161    Willie Cauley-Stein  ...    1626161,1610612758  18/19
10620   1626195      Willy Hernangomez  ...    1626195,1610612766  18/19
10621    201163        Wilson Chandler  ...     201163,1610612746  18/19
10622   1627812           Yogi Ferrell  ...    1627812,1610612758  18/19
10623   1629139          Yuta Watanabe  ...    1629139,1610612763  18/19
10624   1628380           Zach Collins  ...    1628380,1610612757  18/19
10625    203897            Zach LaVine  ...     203897,1610612741  18/19
10626   1629155            Zach Lofton  ...    1629155,1610612765  18/19
10627      2585          Zaza Pachulia  ...       2585,1610612765  18/19
10628   1627753                Zhou Qi  ...    1627753,1610612745  18/19

[10629 rows x 66 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help with this, it worked for me. I was wondering where you got the request_url. And how would I find the request URL for other stats pages?

Comment: Also make sure you’re accepting the solutions to your posts/questions by clicking “accept”